# How can I get an unreserved ClearCase check using Perl?

Tags: perl, clearcase

I need help on below requirement.

I have a extracted report where I used to get "revision number", element details, version path, changeset.

I need to:

1. Create a temporary directory using a Perl script for each revision.
2. Do an unreserved check out for the each element map with each revision and put into the created temporary folders.

I am able to create the temporary directory (e.g-for 100 revision number able to create 100 folders) but need help to write piece of code to do a unreserved checkout (prior to this create activity, set activity) each element associated with the each revision and put the file into the particular created folder. Also implement a undo unreserve checkout after the successful copy.

The data are like,

```
Revision#       Element                    version_path            changeset
-------  ---------------------------     ---------------          ------------
1  C:\views\xyz_mn-11\gahdg\test.java    \main\sdgks-1111_Int\3"  "C:\views\xyz_mn-11 
                                                               \gahdg\test.java@@\main
                                                                \sdgks-1111_Int\3"         
2
3
4
```

Please give some suggestions or valuable guidance on this.

Comment: I have tried this from CMD
cleartool checkout -unr -nc -out -ver \main\sdgks-1111_Int\3 test.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to execute an external command from Perl is to use [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

```
my $cmd = 'cleartool checkout -unr -nc -out -ver \main\sdgks-1111_Int\3 test.java';
if (system $cmd) {
    die "Error: $cmd";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check also the question [How can I interact with ClearCase from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273200/how-can-i-interact-with-clearcase-from-perl/2273896#2273896), where you will be able to execute cleartool command in Perl with the [`CCCmd` package](http://pastie.org/827197).

```
CCCmd::ClearToolNoError("cleartool checkout -unr -nc -out -ver \main\sdgks-1111_Int\3 test.java");
```

However, after reading [`checkout` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm), I am not sure this is the right syntax

```
cleartool checkout -unr -nc -out /my/temp/file -ver test.java@@\main\sdgks-1111_Int\3
```

would be more like it, using the *extended pathname* form to reference the right version to checkout from `test.java`.