# Checkin history of a user in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

Is there a way to find out the checkin history of a user in a stream?

I know that i can get the history by looking at all the activities in a stream. But the change set in an activity doesnt show the date the file is checkedin.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changeset of an activity can show the date of the files. You just need to combine your **[`describe`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm)** command with a **[`fmt_ccase`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)** format instruction.

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[versions]CQp\n" activity:myActivity@/pvobName
```

For each of the output:

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%u %n %d" aFile@@/main/branches/x
```

Note: On Windows, you can list all the activities for a given user.
First, go into a UCM view associated with the relevant stream. Then:

```
for /f  %x in ('cleartool lsact -cview -fmt "%Xn %u\n" ^| findstr "username"') 
  do cleartool desc -fmt "%[versions]CQp\n" %x
```

You can also script this in Perl (which would then be portable, both on Windows and Unix).
See SO question "[How can I interact with ClearCase from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273200/how-can-i-interact-with-clearcase-from-perl)"