# How to query author name (username) of an element using perl?

Tags: perl, scripting, clearcase

I'm using clearcase as version control. Now I have a requirement to update the files which are doesn't having file headers must be properly updated. I am planning to create a simple script to do that. But I wanted to make sense even it's automated headers. So I'd like to the user name of the last user who have created the LATEST version of the particular element (file). How can I query this information using perl?

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Comment: You might find useful info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2273200/725418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [TLP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp) comments, you first query with a classic `cleartool` command, then you parse the result through your Perl script.

See [`fmt_ccase`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) to make the right `cleartool describe` of that element, displaying only the author name.