# How to execute cleartool command within perl

Tags: perl, clearcase, cleartool

Sorry if its to naive. I am wanting to write a simple PERL script that will accept two arguments(Here Commit Labels) which are taken as inputs to cleartool command and provides me with a suitable output.
My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file1 = system('cleartool find . -version "lbtype($ARGV[0])" -print > filename1');
$file2 = system('cleartool find . -version "lbtype($ARGV[1])" -print > filename2');
$file3 = system('diff filename1 filename2 > changeset');
print $ARGV[0];
print $ARGV[1];
print $file3;
close filename1;
close filename2;
close changeset
```

The output now is 3 empty files: filename1,filename2 and changeset.
But i need the files committed between the two committed labels.

Could anyone shed light as to where i am going wrong!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$file1 = system("cleartool find . -version 'lbtype($ARGV[0])' -print > filename1");
```

instead of

```
$file1 = system('cleartool find . -version "lbtype($ARGV[0])" -print > filename1');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked as i had expected. But could you reason out the difference of using ' "" ' and " ' ' " inside system() call that caused the difference?

Comment: If you use variables in single quotes those variables are not interpolated. perl treats variables as string literals. if you use double quotes perl interpolates them as variables

Answer (score 0):

You have also some Perl package to facilitate the execution of `cleartool` commands.

- [package `CCCmd`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2273896/6309): you can see it illustrated in "[How can I interact with ClearCase from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2273896/6309)"
- [`ClearCase::CtCmd`](http://search.cpan.org/~ratl/CtCmd-1.08/CtCmd.pm)

That would allow to directly get the result in an array, instead of a file (even though you can dump that array in a file if you need to)

```
@res = ClearCase::CtCmd::exec("find . -version 'lbtype($ARGV[0])' -print");
```